# How can I configure the buttons of my wacom tablet?

Tags: 11.10, wacom, graphics-tablet

I have a Wacom Bamboo tablet (MTE-450A). It works out of the box on 11.10, even the scrolling function works (it used not to).

Unfortunately the four buttons are assigned to things I don't know. How can I reconfigure them to buttons I want, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `xsetwacom` command line utility.

Should be installed by default.

Example: use `xsetwacom --list devices` to get the list of devices.

`xsetwacom --set <device here> button1 2`
Would set button 1 on whatever device to button 2, or right click.

Explore the other flags for xsetwacom with `man xsetwacom`.
Try `xsetwacom --get <option here>` to see what options or key-mappings are available.

Comment: That is nice. Are these settings stored? Or do I have to make it everytime I restart or replug my tablet?
What if I want to map Shift to one of the buttons? (I want to hold it down doing things)

Comment: If it doesn't store your settings permanently either make a startup script, or store the options permanently in your x11 (xorg.conf/xorg.conf.d) config file (try the .xinitrc file in your home dir). Using the xinitrc file, options will be loaded everytime you login. I use xfce and have the option to also run a specific script when a USB device is plugged in (for hotplugging). See these two links for more information: a) http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/index_old.php/howto/xsetwacom b) http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Tablet_Configuration

Comment: For assigning hotkeys to the buttons, this is more than possible as they can even be chained together to make "macros". Use `xsetwacom --list modifiers` for a complete list of the key modifiers you can use on your system. You can simply place them in order of execution separated by spaces.

Comment: It may also be safer to create your own conf file for wacom as: /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/52-wacom-options.conf and place any options you want active by default in there! Modifying the xorg.conf file can damage the x system.

Comment: But I can't get the modifier pressed while I press my tablet's button. (This is interesting for me because e.g. I want do to multiple clicks and other actions while holding down the Shift key)

Comment: Not sure why it would behave like that... Maybe a bug.

Comment: No, I was just too dumb :) I kept doing `xsetwacom --set 17 Button 1 "key +shift -shift"` but now I got it working with `xsetwacom --set 17 Button 1 "key shift"`. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to bamboo dock
2. Go to tablet
3. Select tablet settings:

   - double click to open
   - choose the button you wish to modify on the tablet schematic
   - in drop down menu, pick "key stroke"
   - enter key stroke, such as: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (for repeated reverse)

Comment: What is "cmd"? Is that a key? If you are using an Apple keyboard, please mention that; it's not a standard key for most people.